# How to create parametrized matrix

Tags: matlab, cell-array, function-handle

I would like to create parametrized matrix with given relationship between arguments like this:

```
B= @(A) [1*A(1), 2*A(2), 3*A(3), 4*A(4)];
```

But matrix is huge and cannot be created by constant expression like this. I need something like this:

```
for i=1:N
    B(i) = @(A) i*A(i);
end
```

Creating matrix this way is not possible and the cell array did not helped me, because this (bellow) is also not valid.

```
B = @(A) cell(1,N);
for i=vec
    B(i) = @(A) i*A(i);
end
```

Comment: `B = @(A) [1:numel(A)].*A`?

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a function?

```
function B = create_matrix(A,n)
    B = zeros(1,n);
    for ii=1:n
        B(ii) = ii*A(i);
    end
end
```

Comment: This is what I have now. But if I put B = create_matrix(A,N), then the matrix is probably allocated newly. I want to speed it up with knowledge of constant dimensions and relationships of parameters inside matrix B - so constant dimensions and variable values due to inserted parameter A.

Comment: please, add a minimal reproducible example of what you want. expected input and output and why this answer does not help you and what you have tried to do

Comment: In C langugage, allocation of memory would be something like below and then C[i] will contain pointers to members of A and B. If A and B changes, then C changes. const double* C = (double*) calloc(N, sizeof(double));

Comment: @Ales100 That is what `B = zeros(1,n);` does: it allocates an array of N doubles and initializes it to zeros.

Comment: @beaker but it allocates it every function call -> every update. What I have shown allocates memory only once and then are changes solved by links.